# Get updated div size when content size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a div that contains several inner divs. In my javascript/jQuery code a function executes, that changes the size of the inner divs using the jQuery css()  function. In another function after the first one, I need to read the size of the outer div. Its size should have increased according to the size increase of its contents.

So basically it looks like this:

```
resizeInnerDivs();
//...do something else...
doSomethingWithOuterDivSize();
```

When doSomethingWithOuterDivSize is entered, IE8 and IE9 still get the old size for the outer div. IE10, Firefox and Chrome on the other hand return the updated size.

I assume that IE8 and IE9 are not done with recalculating the new size. I tried wrapping `doSomethingWithOuterDivSize();` with a `setTimeout` call. If I wait long enough, I can get a better (but not necessarily correct) size value, depending on the timeout.

Can I somehow force the recalculation of the outer div? How can I get the correct values in IE8 and IE9 as well?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: What exactly are you calculating in your functions? Why can't you use the normal CSS flow to re-size your DIVs?

Comment: Well, my question is very much simplified, the real code is of course a lot more complex. However, the specific details of what the complete code does are not relevant to the question. Suffice it to say: I need to trigger some actions depending on the height of the outer div. I am not sure what you mean by "the normal CSS flow". Care to explain?

Comment: HTML/CSS resizes its elements automatically by default. Only when people (unnecessarily) start using absolute positioning everywhere, this breaks and you need to "manually" re-size with JavaScript. Just stay away from absolute positioning as much as possible (modifying the design if necessary) and everything is fine.

Comment: Noted, but this is a fixed requirement. Therefore I have no choice but to use JavaScript to manipulate the elements after css has taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
$('.yourClass').width();
$('someElement').width();
$('#someId').width();
$('any valid jQuery/CSS selector').width();
```

Resource: http://api.jquery.com/width/

`$.width()` will give you computed width of your element.

Comment: no, this doesn't help. Again I can set and read the dimensions of the _inner_ divs without problems. It is the outer div that I get an old value. It doesn't make a difference if I use height(), width(), css('height') or look in the attributes. Important is the value itself that just did not yet get updated, not the method of retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have either of these two:

1. The inner divs don't affect your outer div width on IE.
2. The inner divs are not finished rendering before you are trying to get the
   width of outer div, thus you still get the old width.

You can check this by querying width in the console manually:

```
console.log($('outer_div_selector').width())
```

If this returns the correct (updated) width, then you are having issue #2. You can solve it like this:

```
$('outer_div_selector').width(); // this will force rendering to finish before executing the next line
doSomethingWithOuterDivSize();
```

Otherwise you have an CSS issue (eg. make sure all floats are correctly cleared).